# Application not working due to Kubernetes Ingress Conroller Fake Certificate

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, rancher

I'm trying to deploy an app using Kubernetes and Rancher,but I get the error "The certificate for this site is not valid." How can I change the certificate from  Kubernetes Ingress Conroller Fake Certificate to another certificate? Should I do it from Rancher or from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Ingress Conroller Fake Certificate to another certificate?

The basic requirement for ingress TLS is a TLS/SSL certificate. You can obtain these certificates in the following ways.

**Self-Signed Certificates:** TLS certificate created and signed by our own Certificage Authority. It is great optionfor development environments where you can share the rootCA with the team so that browsers can trust the certificate. Check out create self-signed certificate blog to create your own certificates.

**Purchase an SSL Certificate**: You need to buy an SSL certificate from a well-known certificate authority trusted by browsers & operating systems for production use cases. Check out the top SSL Providers for more information.

**Use Letsencrpt Certificate**: Letsencrypt is a non-profit trusted certificate authority that provides free TLS certificates.
For more information follow this [document](https://devopscube.com/configure-ingress-tls-kubernetes/) .

**To update the certificate follow these steps:**

To update  ssl certificate for your (ingress) https load balancer.
When you created the cluster please executed these commands:

> kubectl create secret tls mysecret --key mykey.key --cert mycert.crt

> kubectl apply -f ./ingress.yaml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

kind: Ingress

metadata:

name: ingress

annotations:

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /

ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
```

spec:
tls:

- secretName: mysecret

backend:

```
serviceName: nginx-nodeport-service

servicePort: 80
```

For more information follow this [document](https://groups.google.com/g/kubernetes-users/c/eXKOhGaElBk?pli=1). also refer to [troubleshooting the Rancher server kubernetes cluster](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/installation/resources/troubleshooting/#cert-cn-is-kubernetes-ingress-controller-fake-certificate).

Comment: I am facing this situation https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/issues/689.  Could you please suggest.